# Python chat clients not updating

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, tkinter

I am working on a GUI based chat program.
I am using someone else's server which has worked well for many people so I am assuming the problem is with my client's code.
When I run a single instance of the client it works perfectly, but if I run two instances of the client on the same computer the listener stops responding when the 2nd client logs in.

```
# server is from socket module
# chat_box is a tkinter ListBox
# both are copies of global variable
class listener_thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, server, chat_box):
        super(listener_thread, self).__init__()
        self.server = server
        self.chat_box = chat_box

    def run(self):
        try:
            update = self.server.recv(1024)
            msg = update.decode("utf-8")
            if msg != "":
                self.chat_box.insert(END, msg)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

I've verified that the server is putting each client on a different port. The server is receiving the messages. When 'Michael' logs in and says 'Hi' it updates in his chat_box.
 
Though, the clients are no longer updating their histories after 'Dave' logs in.
Yet, the server continues to show that it is receiving the messages from both clients.

```
#This is the server output
#Hi is Michael
#Yo is Dave
#So Michael is still connecting and transmitting after Dave connects

   Michael - ('127.0.0.1', 56263) connected
Hi
   Dave - ('127.0.0.1', 56264) connected
Yo
Hi
```

The network connection is working properly. It just locks up the list_box updating threads. 
No exceptions are being thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem.
I needed to make the chat_history_listbox as a ListBox initially, instead of None
I needed to put the receive code into a function, with a loop and an exit condition

```
def receive_func():
    global server, chat_history_listbox
    while True:
        try:
            update = server.recv(1024)
        except OSError as e:
            update = None
            break
            connect()
        msg = update.decode("utf-8")
        if msg != "":
            chat_history_listbox.insert(END, msg)
```

I needed to make the thread call a function and make it a daemon

```
listener = Thread(target=receive_func, daemon=True)
listener.start()
```

This got it working with multiple clients